# Force IE 7 Compatiblity Mode in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, compatibility, mode

I have a c# asp.net website and needs to run in compatibility mode. The website runs (forced) in a popup. I have searched on google and stackoverflow about how to force compatibility mode and found scripts like:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=7"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8">
```

I have tried some of above but when I start the website in the browser and then pres on the F12 key, I see the following mode:

Browser Mode: IE8
Document Mode: Quirks

So the browser mode not changed to the compatibility mode.

Does someone know what my problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility Mode is one of the Browser Mode settings; you don't have any ability to change the users browser to compatibility mode. You can only control the document mode of your page - this is what you're seeing in the examples you provided.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

This will force the document into IE7 Standards Mode. If you were to use the *EmulateIE7* option, that would look to your doctype to determine if it ought to be Standards, or Quirks. This is the only option offered to you regarding how your page is viewed in the users browser.

Be sure to place that within the `<head>` region of the page you wish to affect. Additionally, when you're checking the Document Mode, look for which options has "(Page Default)" next to it and not which options is selected.

IE will respect your manual override over the x-ua meta tag. It may be the case that you accidentally moved set the document mode to Quirks while testing, even though the default mode for the page has been adjusted to IE7 by the meta tag.

Further Reading: [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)