# Not using Compatibility Mode

Tags: internet-explorer

Could anyone tell me why [this page](http://www.westberks.gov.uk/frontline/describe_case.aspx) isn't forcing the browser into Compatibility Mode?

I've added this to the HEAD:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884107/force-ie-7-compatiblity-mode-in-ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE>` should be at the very first line of the file. `X-UA-Compatible` should be before any `link` or `script` or anything else, which possible could affect to the document mode. Also your `X-UA-Compatible` is malformed, it should be `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`. `initpage()` is not defined when `body.onload` fires.

Comment: Problem solved. Moved the X-UA-Compatible just below the <HEAD> tag.